# Does access control matter for deleted constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Is there a difference in behavior between whether an explicitly deleted constructor is `public`, `protected` or `private`?

For example, a non copyable class would have a deleted copy constructor (and deleted copy assignment). The constructor would not be available to neither subclasses (or friends) nor to outside users of the class, because it doesn't exist, regardless of its access control.

The only difference I see would be in what manner different scopes would see that the copy constructor doesn't exist - whether it is just not there (as far as that scope knows) or it is explicitly deleted.

Now, it might be beneficial to have the best formal interface for the class - that is, if everyone should know that the class is non-copyable, it should be publicly deleted. Compiler error messages might also be more informative. But other than that - would there be any actual observable difference in the class behavior? That is, something one could do with a class which has its deleted constructor with access X which he couldn't do if that constructor had access Y?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's overload resolution that makes the program ill-formed in this case, and not access specifiers (which are checked later), there is no difference in outcome. The compiler will always complain that a deleted function was picked.

But since the idiom before C++11 was *"declare but not define a private copy c'tor to disable copying"*, I would consider it going along with the same idiom, and therefore favorable. You are using the "old slang" with some new language to describe the same thing, except better.

Comment: I actually think that in most cases making a deleted copy ctor `public` makes more sense semantically in most cases - when you wish to publicly state the class's *interface* that is isn't copyable. Regardless, I'm curious whether there's any difference in behavior (and for constructors in general, not just the copy one which I used as an example).

Comment: @Danra - The only difference it makes is ultimately stylistic. Since many style guides will bunch public/protected/private members in their own "sections". And if one takes that into account, the same argument works in reverse. Making the c'tor private pushes it outside of the classes public API, the class is not copyable.

Comment: @StoryTeller except if it isn't deleted, it still can be copied by friend or own facilities

Comment: @Swift - Yes, that's another thing. If one does opt to define it later, it affects the smallest scope possible by default. Also good in my book.